# $\newcommand{\co}{\overline{\mathrm{co}}}\co(A)-\co(B) \subseteq \co(A-B)$ in a linear topological space $X$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to prove that $\newcommand{\co}{\overline{\mathrm{co} }} \co(A)-\co(B) \subseteq \co(A-B)$ in a linear topological space (topological vector space) $X$.

Here $\co(A)$ is the closed convex hull of $A$, the closure of the convex hull of $A$ in $X$.

Here is some argument which is quite vague for me: Since $x \to a-x$ is an affine homeomorphism for all $a\in A$, we get $a-\co(B)=\co(a-B) \subseteq \co(A-B)$. Then for arbitrary fixed $b \in \co(B)$, we have $a-b \in \co(A-B)$ for all $a \in A$. Hence $\co(A)-b=\co(A-b)\subseteq \co(A-B)$ for all  $b \in \co(B)$. At this point the claim is that the proof is complete.

Any other more direct proof or explanation of this one in detail would help.

Comment: I don't understand the notation at all. What is $cl-co(A)$ and what is the difference between this and $\overline{co}(A)$?

Comment: Is a "linear topological space" the same thing as a "topological vector space"?

Comment: $cl-A$ and $\overline{A}$ are the same thing. Since there is only one topology in the pictures. Yes linear topological space is the same as topological vector space.

Comment: $cl-A$ is *terrible* notation for the closure of $A$, especially because the minus sign is used for subtraction in the same formula. Use $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ instead.

Comment: I edited the question to make it readable. Having fixed the formatting, I now understand the question, and the proof as written seems quite clear and direct to me. Can you elaborate on what steps you can't follow or what seems vague about it?